# How do I change collection view constraints manually?

Tags: swift, xcode, constraints, collectionview

Is it possible to add constraints to collection view cells in some way so they change size in relation to the device they're on? I've googled a bit and can just find ways to do it programmatically, which I fail to implement. :P If not, what's the easiest way to do it?

Also, how do I change the spacing size between the cells?

Comment: If programmatically, is it done through UICollectionviewFlolayoutDelegate? How do I implement it to work with all devices?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change UICollectionViewCell size programmatically in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31662155/how-to-change-uicollectionviewcell-size-programmatically-in-swift)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out! Remove this post?