# How can I change the size of a collectionview's cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

my collectionview starts out like this:
[initial screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPsmz.png)

when the user swipes up on the collection it expands like so:
[second screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzNhk.png)

how can I change the size of the cells when the collection view expands?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change UICollectionViewCell size programmatically in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31662155/how-to-change-uicollectionviewcell-size-programmatically-in-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In english:**

You need to set the cells' height equals to the collection view height, and every time the collection resize you need to refresh the layout.

**In iOS language**

you need to conform your view controller the the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

and use the

`func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize`

to resize the cells

```
extension YourViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {


        let height = collectionView.frame.size.height
        let width = //make your calculation

        return  CGSize(width: width, height: height)
  }
}
```

something like this